# SQLITE JDBC does not INSERT not fetches data with SELECT

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying an example to use SQLITE JDBC (org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc version 3.30.1) to do a simple insert into the db and display the inserted row. I have tried all possible methods even using the standard code given with SQLITE Java but it does not INSERT nor fetches any rows from the DB.

Request anyone to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
import com.ncsp.server.db.CreateDDL;
import com.ncsp.server.db.DBConnect;
import com.ncsp.server.model.audit.AuditType;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

public class DBUtil {

    public Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/rv037030/.ncsp-server/ncsp-server.sqlite.db";

        try {
            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established. JDBC URL: " + url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("DRIVEr MANAGER ERROR. URL " + url);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conn;
    }

    public void fetchAudit() {
        Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> retVal = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        // Insert Statement.
        String insert = "insert into ncsp_audit_events (component, created, details, event_type, jobId, user) " +
                "values ('TEST1',"
                + Timestamp.from(Instant.now())
                + ", 'Sample Details', 'EVENT_TYPE',"
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                +", 'USER')";

        System.out.println("Insert QUERY: " + insert);

        // Select Statement.
        String select = "select t.event_type from ncsp_audit_events t";
        System.out.println("Select query: " + select);

        try (Connection conn = connect();
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

            boolean inserted = stmt.execute(insert);
            System.out.println("Inserted: " + inserted);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, String> output = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                output.put("event_type", rs.getString("event_type"));
                output.put("component", rs.getString("component"));
                output.put("jobId", String.valueOf(rs.getLong("jobId")));
                output.put("details", rs.getString("details"));
                output.put("user", rs.getString("user"));
                output.put("created", String.valueOf(rs.getTimestamp("created")));

                System.out.println("OUTPUT: " + output);
                retVal.put(1, output);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("RECORDS: "+ retVal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
        util.fetchAudit();
    }
}
```

This is the output when I execute the program:

> Insert QUERY: insert into ncsp_audit_events (component, created, details, event_type, jobId, >user) values ('TEST1',2020-02-06 14:30:56.021758, 'Sample Details', 'EVENT_TYPE',1581028256029, >'USER')
>   Select query: select t.event_type from ncsp_audit_events t
>   Connection to SQLite has been established. JDBC URL: jdbc:sqlite:/Users/rv037030/.ncsp->server/ncsp-server.sqlite.db
>   [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "14": syntax error)
>   RECORDS: {}

Comment: Bind values to parameters in the query, don't put values directly in a SQL statement. See the jdbc documentation for how to do it with that library.

Comment: Sure @Shawn Thank you. I'll bind them so there would not be an SQL Injection. But I just wanted to see if this simple program works and it kind of bogs me down. Need extra pair of eyes to validate this.

Comment: You most likely need to **commit** the insert.